# Parallel routing - Page refresh

Tags: next.js13, app-router

I have a nextjs 13 App Router App.

I am trying to implement a static header that will be rendered asynchronously making some server requests.
I want to treat the header as it's own page, having also loading.js for example.
It seems like a good idea to use parallel routing for that usecase.

```
--@header
----page.js
----loading.js
--some-page
----page.js
--layout.js
```

```
Layout({header, children}) {
  return <>{header}{children}</>;
}
```

The above setup will yield in 404 uppon page refresh when in /some-page route.
I read that I should have a default.js in my parallel route folder to avoid this.
when I add the default.js, it will not be treated as a page, so the loading.js file will not be rendered before the default is ready, which beats the purpose of this.

anyone has any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `I should have a default.js in my parallel route folder`, as well as in `app` folder (2 default.js files in project as a result)